# React Native Firebase Firestore Cannot read property 'scope' of null

Tags: firebase, react-native

Since today, I have this error when running my app :
node_modules/@firebase/firestore/dist/rn/prebuilt.rn-d6d8673f.js: Cannot read property 'scope' of null

```
"react-native": "~0.63.4"
```

```
"firebase": "8.10.0"
```

Any idea?

I already removed my node_modules and reinstalled.

Comment: Happening same for "react-native": "0.65.3", and "firebase": "^8.2.8",